# Deriving children of a 2-of-3 multisig address with 3 xpubs as the starting point

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets

I want to derive the children of a HD Multisig address using each of the xpubs following BitGo specs,

currently, I have 3 xpubs and can get to the point where I can derive main address very similar to this test from bitcoinjs lib:

```
    const pubkeys = [ // b58 encoded xpubs
      '026477115981fe981a6918a6297d9803c4dc04f328f22041bedff886bbc2962e01',
      '02c96db2302d19b43d4c69368babace7854cc84eb9e061cde51cfa77ca4a22b8b9',
      '03c6103b3b83e4a24a0e33a4df246ef11772f9992663db0c35759a5e2ebf68d8e9',
    ].map(hex => Buffer.from(hex, 'hex'));
    const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2sh({
      redeem: bitcoin.payments.p2ms({ m: 2, pubkeys }),
    });

    >>> '36NUkt6FWUi3LAWBqWRdDmdTWbt91Yvfu7'
```

My question is - if I wanted to derive children from a setup like this using CKD, how would I do that? Where do I get my HDNode to start deriving? I want to do address discovery to find all addresses where funds may live.

Comment: This question is more about the library you are using than Bitcoin or BIP32 itself.